# Get values from a result array javascript

Tags: javascript

```
Array[7998]
[0 … 99]
0:"        1    2015-01-14 13:27:07 1   0   2   0"
1:"        1    2015-01-14 13:30:11 1   0   2   0"
2:"        1    2015-01-14 13:33:34 1   0   2   0"
3:"        1    2015-01-14 13:33:43 1   0   2   0"
4:"        2    2015-01-21 10:54:37 1   0   1   0"
5:"        2    2015-02-03 11:39:57 1   0   1   0"
6:"        2    2015-02-03 11:44:56 1   4   1   0"
7:"        1    2015-02-03 11:44:59 1   4   2   0"
8:"        2    2015-02-03 11:49:49 1   0   1   0"
9:"      221    2015-02-03 11:49:51 1   0   1   0"
10:"      221   2015-02-03 11:49:53 1   0   1   0"
11:"      221   2015-02-03 11:52:07 1   0   1   0"
12:"        1   2015-02-26 17:29:24 1   4   2   0"
```

Hi! I get this result from this code:

```
function onReadFile(file){
  var txt = file.target.result;
  var list = txt.split('\n');
//  var result = list.map(function(item){
//     return item.split('\n');
//  });
  console.log(list);
}
```

Is there a way to get just the first three values or columns? The first three columns represent the Id, date, and time so I need to extract just the three like so..

```
[1,2015-01-14,13:27:07][1,2015-01-14,13:30:11][1,2015-01-14,13:33:34][...]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are those spaces or tabs between each?

Comment: Show an example of the expected result (for 3 rows at least)? Do you want them as objects?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: please see my edit.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 Objects will be better! Check my answer! I used objects not arrays! Let me know if you want me to update it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var text = "   1    2015-01-14 13:30:11 1   0   2   0\n        1    2015-01-14 13:33:34 1   0   2   0\n        1    2015-01-14 13:33:43 1   0   2   0";

var list = 
text.split('\n')                 // split the lines
    .map(function(line) {        // map the lines
      var parts = line.trim()    // trim the current line (remove surrounding spaces)
                  .split(/\s+/); // split the cols by multiple spaces (space, tabs, ...)

      return parts.slice(0, 3);  // return an array like your desired output (just the first three cols of each row)
      
      // IF YOU WANT THE RESULT TO BE AN OBJECT THEN REMOVE THE ABOVE RETURN STATEMENT AND UNCOMMENT THE CODE BELLOW

      //var o = {};
      //o.id = parts[0];
      //o.date = parts[1];
      //o.time = parts[2];

      //return o;
    });

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Requirement is to return an array, not object.

Comment: @guest271314 See my comment under the question! I answered before he posted the desired output! So I'm now waiting for his response! This could be what he really wants!

Comment: Object is great! However, I need to place each line in a google sheet and the way to put it is through my sample output above. But, if you can teach me how to iterate through the objects to get to my sample above that would be a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

You can split by a string using a regex for multiple white spaces.

```
var fields = list.split(/\s+/);
console.log(fields);
```

And the first three columns are at index 1, 2 and 3, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can split on the spaces and them map it to the desired values.

```
//the function that looks at the item entry and gets the 
//needed values.
function parse (item) {
    var items = item.split(' ')

  var actualItems = items.filter(x=>x !== "")

    return [
      actualItems[0], 
      actualItems[1],
      actualItems[2]
    ]
  }
}

//your array of items
var items = [
"        1    2015-01-14 13:27:07 1   0   2   0",
"        1    2015-01-14 13:30:11 1   0   2   0"
]

//transform your array to appropriate values.
var itemData = items.map(parse);

console.log(itemData)
```

Comment: Requirement is to return an array, not object.

Comment: actually no, he's pretty clear in his response that an object of the values would be better.

Comment: _"like so..`[1,2015-01-14,13:27:07][1,2015-01-14,13:30:11][1,2015-01-14,13:33:34][...]`"_

Comment: Difficult to empirically determine what is "better". Only indicated actual text of requirement and `javascript` at original Question.

Comment: Although I understand your statement, but when choosing between an array and an object in this context one could argue the object is more appropriate.  If you consider that an array is a collection of items this really doesn't fit that.  (you wouldn't really use map or filter on the array)
You have to know the position to get the appropriate item where an object explicitly tells you what it is.

You are right though, the op may be constrained by something else, but looking at the progression of the question, it seems like there is a choice.  To me the object is much clearer.

Comment: Interestingly OP accepted Answer which was revised from returning an object to return same result as this users' Answer, after posted same comment at the users' original Answer.

Comment: Ha!  We both got beat out on that one, although you are clearly right, that is what he asked for.

Answer (score 0):

`.match()` characters that are not space characters, `.slice()` first three elements of resulting array

```js
var list = ["        1    2015-01-14 13:27:07 1   0   2   0"
,"        1    2015-01-14 13:30:11 1   0   2   0"
,"        1    2015-01-14 13:33:34 1   0   2   0"
,"        1    2015-01-14 13:33:43 1   0   2   0"
,"        2    2015-01-21 10:54:37 1   0   1   0"
,"        2    2015-02-03 11:39:57 1   0   1   0"
,"        2    2015-02-03 11:44:56 1   4   1   0"
,"        1    2015-02-03 11:44:59 1   4   2   0"
,"        2    2015-02-03 11:49:49 1   0   1   0"
,"      221    2015-02-03 11:49:51 1   0   1   0"
,"      221   2015-02-03 11:49:53 1   0   1   0"
,"      221   2015-02-03 11:52:07 1   0   1   0"
,"        1   2015-02-26 17:29:24 1   4   2   0"];

var result = list.map(function(text) {
                   return text.match(/[^\s]+/g).slice(0, 3)
                 });

console.log(result);
```